# pd.Series.to_list() changing dtype

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, google-colaboratory

When I am programming on colab, I keep running into this issue:

Here is my df:

```
0                1
0    [2.7436598593417045e-05, 3.731542193080655e-05]
1    [8.279973504084787e-05, 2.145002145002145e-05]
2    [0.00022534319714215346, 0.0002031172259231674]
3    [3.239841667031943e-05, 2.7771297808289177e-05]
4    [0.00011311134356928321, 9.428422928088026e-05]
```

I want to get the data from df[1] into a list of lists so I can feed it into my model. To do so, I run:

```
df[1].to_list()
```

and i get:

```
['[2.7436598593417045e-05, 3.731542193080655e-05]',
 '[8.279973504084787e-05, 2.145002145002145e-05]',
 '[0.00022534319714215346, 0.00020311722592316746]',
 '[3.239841667031943e-05, 2.7771297808289177e-05]',
 '[0.00011311134356928321, 9.428422928088026e-05]']
```

which is a list of strings which I cannot use to feed into the model. I use this code all the time locally and it works fine, but on colab I get this result. Any ideas? The result I want is:

```
[[2.7436598593417045e-05, 3.731542193080655e-05],
 [8.279973504084787e-05, 2.145002145002145e-05],
 [0.00022534319714215346, 0.00020311722592316746],
 [3.239841667031943e-05, 2.7771297808289177e-05],
 [0.00011311134356928321, 9.428422928088026e-05]]
```

Comment: In the `df` are those column elements actually lists, or are they also strings?  What's the source?  The column dtype is object either way.  What's the source of this `df`.  If loaded from a csv, look at the text file.  It will have quoted strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ast.literal_eval`

```
from ast import literal_eval

df[1].map(literal_eval).to_list()

[[2.7436598593417045e-05, 3.731542193080655e-05],
 [8.279973504084787e-05, 2.145002145002145e-05],
 [0.00022534319714215346, 0.00020311722592316746],
 [3.239841667031943e-05, 2.7771297808289177e-05],
 [0.00011311134356928321, 9.428422928088026e-05]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I make a dataframe with list elements:

```
In [135]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,[1,3]],[2,[3,5]]])                                                     
In [136]: df                                                                                           
Out[136]: 
   0       1
0  1  [1, 3]
1  2  [3, 5]
In [137]: df.dtypes                                                                                    
Out[137]: 
0     int64
1    object
dtype: object
In [138]: df[1].to_list()                                                                              
Out[138]: [[1, 3], [3, 5]]
```

Doing the same with strings of lists:

```
In [139]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,'[1,3]'],[2,'[3,5]']])                                                
In [140]: df1                                                                                          
Out[140]: 
   0      1
0  1  [1,3]
1  2  [3,5]
In [141]: df1.dtypes                                                                                   
Out[141]: 
0     int64
1    object
dtype: object
In [142]: df1[1].to_list()                                                                             
Out[142]: ['[1,3]', '[3,5]']
```

`df1` looks just like `df`, except the column elements are strings.

`df1` type of frame often results from saving `df` to a `csv`, and reloading it.

```
In [143]: df.to_csv('test.csv')                                                                        
In [144]: cat test.csv                                                                                 
,0,1
0,1,"[1, 3]"
1,2,"[3, 5]"
```

to match the table format, it has to quote the lists.