# ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated even after using tuple in np.concatenate

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to apply a working script (`code2` on `input-2`) that converts data frame string entry to separate rows on my dataset (`output-1`) that looks similar to `input-2`. Strangely, I am getting the ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays error. I googled and searched StackOverflow but with no success.

**Error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-310-36a8923ddf69> in <module>
----> 1 explode(df3, ['longitude','altitude', 'speed'], fill_value='',preserve_index=True)

<ipython-input-308-31db0d7d3bc1> in explode(df, lst_cols, fill_value, preserve_index)
     19                 index=idx)
     20              .assign(**{col:np.concatenate(df.loc[lens>0, col].values)
---> 21                             for col in lst_cols}))
     22     # append those rows that have empty lists
     23     if (lens == 0).any():

<ipython-input-308-31db0d7d3bc1> in <dictcomp>(.0)
     19                 index=idx)
     20              .assign(**{col:np.concatenate(df.loc[lens>0, col].values)
---> 21                             for col in lst_cols}))
     22     # append those rows that have empty lists
     23     if (lens == 0).any():

ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

**Json file (soverflowq.json)**

```
{'longitude': [24.64977040886879, 24.65014273300767, 24.6501], 'altitude': [41.2, 34.2, 24.6501],'url': 'https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/workouts/392337037', 'userId': 10921916, 'speed': [9.0792, 13.284, 24.6501]}
{'longitude': [22.44977040886879, 27.65014273300767, 24.6501], 'altitude': [38.4, 39.0, 24.6501],'url': 'https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921915/workouts/392337038', 'userId': 10921915, 'speed': [9.0792, 13.284, 24.6501]}
{'longitude': [24.64977040886879, 24.65014273300767, 24.6501], 'altitude': [41.2, 34.2, 24.6501],'url': 'https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/workouts/392337037', 'userId': 1092116, 'speed': [9.0792, 13.284, 24.6501]}
{'longitude': [22.44977040886879, 27.65014273300767, 24.6501], 'altitude': [38.4, 39.0, 24.6501],'url': 'https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921915/workouts/392337038', 'userId': 1092191, 'speed': [9.0792, 13.284, 24.6501]}
```

**Code-1**

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# read a file line-by-line into a list
with open('soverflowq.json') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

# split each line into one column
data = [re.split(r'\s+(?=\d+$)', l) for l in data]  
# constructing dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['all_cols'])   
# split further and rename the cols
df[['new0','new1', 'new2', 'new3', 'new4', 'new5', 'new6', 'new7', 'new8', 'new9']] = df['all_cols'].str.split(r"\, '|\,'|\':",expand=True) 

# remove [, ], ', }, \n
cols_to_check = ['new0','new1','new3','new5', 'new9'] 
df[cols_to_check] = df[cols_to_check].replace({'\'':''}, regex=True)
df[cols_to_check] = df[cols_to_check].replace({'{':''}, regex=True)
df[cols_to_check] = df[cols_to_check].replace({'}':''}, regex=True)
df[cols_to_check] = df[cols_to_check].replace({'\n':''}, regex=True)
df[cols_to_check] = df[cols_to_check].replace({'\n':''}, regex=True)
#df[cols_to_check] = df[cols_to_check].replace({'\[':''}, regex=True)
#df[cols_to_check] = df[cols_to_check].replace({'\]':''}, regex=True)

#drop cols
df1= df.drop(columns=['all_cols', 'new0', 'new2', 'new4', 'new6', 'new8'])

# rename cols
df1.columns = ['longitude', 'altitude', 'url', 'userId', 'speed']

# reorder cols
column_titles =['userId', 'longitude', 'altitude', 'speed', 'url']
df2 = df1.reindex(columns=column_titles)
df3= df2.drop(columns=['url'])
print(df3)
```

**Output-1**

```
      userId                                         longitude  \
0   10921916   [24.64977040886879, 24.65014273300767, 24.6501]   
1   10921915   [22.44977040886879, 27.65014273300767, 24.6501]   
2    1092116   [24.64977040886879, 24.65014273300767, 24.6501]   
3    1092191   [22.44977040886879, 27.65014273300767, 24.6501]   

                 altitude                       speed  
0   [41.2, 34.2, 24.6501]   [9.0792, 13.284, 24.6501]  
1   [38.4, 39.0, 24.6501]   [9.0792, 13.284, 24.6501]  
2   [41.2, 34.2, 24.6501]   [9.0792, 13.284, 24.6501]  
3   [38.4, 39.0, 24.6501]   [9.0792, 13.284, 24.6501]
```

**Code-2**

#### [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows)

```
def explode(df, lst_cols, fill_value='', preserve_index=False):
    # make sure `lst_cols` is list-alike
    if (lst_cols is not None
        and len(lst_cols) > 0
        and not isinstance(lst_cols, (list, tuple, np.ndarray, pd.Series))):
        lst_cols = [lst_cols]
    # all columns except `lst_cols`
    idx_cols = df.columns.difference(lst_cols)
    # calculate lengths of lists
    lens = df[lst_cols[0]].str.len()
    # preserve original index values    
    idx = np.repeat(df.index.values, lens)
    # create "exploded" DF
    res = (pd.DataFrame({
                col:np.repeat(df[col].values, lens)
                for col in idx_cols},
                index=idx)
             .assign(**{col:np.concatenate((df.loc[lens>0, col].values))
                            for col in lst_cols}))
    # append those rows that have empty lists
    if (lens == 0).any():
        # at least one list in cells is empty
        res = (res.append(df.loc[lens==0, idx_cols], sort=False)
                  .fillna(fill_value))
    # revert the original index order
    res = res.sort_index()
    # reset index if requested
    if not preserve_index:        
        res = res.reset_index(drop=True)
    return res
```

**Input-2**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'userid': {0: 10, 1: 2, 2: 12, 3: 13},
    'longitude': {0: [24.64977040886879, 24.64977040886879, 324.64977040886879], 
            1: [24.64977040886879,424.64977040886879,524.64977040886879], 
            2: [124.64977040886879,224.64977040886879 ,224.64977040886879], 
            3: [124.64977040886879,324.64977040886879,424.64977040886879]},
    'altitude': {0: [24.64977040886879, 24.64977040886879, 324.64977040886879], 
            1: [24.64977040886879,424.64977040886879,524.64977040886879], 
            2: [124.64977040886879,224.64977040886879 ,224.64977040886879], 
            3: [124.64977040886879,324.64977040886879,424.64977040886879]},
    'speed': {0: [24.64977040886879, 24.64977040886879, 324.64977040886879], 
            1: [24.64977040886879,424.64977040886879,524.64977040886879], 
            2: [124.64977040886879,224.64977040886879 ,224.64977040886879], 
            3: [124.64977040886879,324.64977040886879,424.64977040886879]},
})



explode(df, ['longitude','altitude', 'speed'], fill_value='',preserve_index=True)
```

**Ouput-2**

```
userid  longitude   altitude    speed
0   10  24.64977    24.64977    24.64977
0   10  24.64977    24.64977    24.64977
0   10  324.64977   324.64977   324.64977
1   2   24.64977    24.64977    24.64977
1   2   424.64977   424.64977   424.64977
1   2   524.64977   524.64977   524.64977
2   12  124.64977   124.64977   124.64977
2   12  224.64977   224.64977   224.64977
2   12  224.64977   224.64977   224.64977
3   13  124.64977   124.64977   124.64977
3   13  324.64977   324.64977   324.64977
3   13  424.64977   424.64977   424.64977
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide a traceback, or sample values from the problem expression.  But based on the title I'm guessing the problem is in the

```
np.concatenate((df.loc[lens>0, col].values))
```

expression.  I can't recreate your `df`, but I suspect the problem with a column of strings (`[24.64977040886879, 24.64977040886879, 324.64977040886879]` may look like a list, but it could well be a string.  Pandas omits quotes in its display.

As an experiment I took one of your `json` lines, and 'parsed' it:

```
In [159]: dd = {'longitude': [24.64977040886879, 24.65014273300767, 24.6501], 'altitude': [41.2, 34.2, 
     ...: 24.6501],'url': 'https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/workouts/392337037', 'userId': 1092
     ...: 1916, 'speed': [9.0792, 13.284, 24.6501]}                                                    
In [160]: dd                                                                                           
Out[160]: 
{'longitude': [24.64977040886879, 24.65014273300767, 24.6501],
 'altitude': [41.2, 34.2, 24.6501],
 'url': 'https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/workouts/392337037',
 'userId': 10921916,
 'speed': [9.0792, 13.284, 24.6501]}
```

and then made a dataframe from it:

```
In [161]: pd.DataFrame(dd)                                                                             
Out[161]: 
   longitude  altitude                                                url    userId    speed
0  24.649770   41.2000  https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/worko...  10921916   9.0792
1  24.650143   34.2000  https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/worko...  10921916  13.2840
2  24.650100   24.6501  https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/worko...  10921916  24.6501
In [162]: _.dtypes                                                                                     
Out[162]: 
longitude    float64
altitude     float64
url           object
userId         int64
speed        float64
dtype: object


In [163]: _161['url']                                                                                  
Out[163]: 
0    https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/worko...
1    https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/worko...
2    https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/worko...
Name: url, dtype: object
In [164]: _161['url'].values                                                                           
Out[164]: 
array(['https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/workouts/392337037',
       'https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/workouts/392337037',
       'https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/workouts/392337037'],
      dtype=object)
```

So this 'values' is an array of strings (object dtype is normal for pandas).  Trying to do a `concatenate` on that produces your error.

```
In [165]: np.concatenate(_161['url'].values)                                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-165-df206e02c51f> in <module>
----> 1 np.concatenate(_161['url'].values)

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

Wrapping that 'values' in `()` doesn't change things.  Adding a comma does make it a tuple:

```
In [168]: np.concatenate((_161['url'].values,))                                                        
Out[168]: 
array(['https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/workouts/392337037',
       'https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/workouts/392337037',
       'https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/workouts/392337037'],
      dtype=object)
```

But concatenate on a 1 element tuple doesn't do anything significant.

I suspectt you need to examine `df.loc[lens>0, col].values`, and understand exactly what it is.  No guesses or blind testing.

Comment: I added the Traceback. I am surprised to see you can not reproduce my data frame (output1). It works on my Jupyter notebook. I created a co-lab [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wF0L3bEvjjdEf0siHDWCteknSsyx7Uyx) so that you can test it. Please try this and let me know.

Comment: Also, I dropped 'url values' from the data frame before I ran the code. So that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Another  case where column elements aren't actually lists, https://stackoverflow.com/q/61531470/901925

Comment: Then this should work no but it didn't `df3[['longitude', 'altitude', 'speed']] = df3[['longitude', 'altitude', 'speed']].values.tolist()`